# Bootstrap tooltip toggles wrong sometimes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-2

I've realized that the **Bootstrap 2.3.2** tooltip doesn't always work properly.
I'm having this problem in :

- Chrome 35.0.1916.114 m
- Firefox 29.0.1
- Opera 21.0.1432.67
- Safari 5.1.7

It seems to work well in IE 9.

If you move the mouse over the tooltip element quite fast (up and down, for example, or right and left), there's a point in which the tooltip won't show when you have the mouse over the element which is suppose to show it.

You can easily reproduce it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44khF/358/).

```
$('[data-rel]').tooltip()
```

Did anyone find a solution for this?

**Update**

---

It looks like the bug still taking place in **Bootstrap 3.1.1**. It seems more difficult to be reproduced, but you still can get it by moving the mouse up and down quite fast for a short distance over and outside the element.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/103/) to reproduce it.

Comment: Same problem here. It's fixed in v3: http://jsfiddle.net/Wy22s/103/

Comment: @Getz I still getting the bug in Chrome (didnt try the others yet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works fine without the animation:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/44khF/360/)

```
$('[data-rel]').tooltip({
    animation: false 
})
```

Comment: I tried playing with delay, selector and container options, but still the same. I think it's a bootstrap bug that will not be fixed because that version is no longer supported.

Comment: but the problem still existing in bootstrap 3. Looks like more difficult to reproduce it, but after a time playing with the mouse you get it anyway.

Comment: Curiously, i don't have the problem on Chrome, Opera and Firefox in bootstrap 3...

Comment: try it by moving the mouse for a very short distance in and out quite fast.

Comment: Indeed, sometimes the tooltip disappears. But if you leave the link and return on it, the tooltip comes back. In 2.3, once it disappears, it fails at coming back...

Comment: Yep, but something is wrong anyway. I will accept your answer as it solves my problem.

Comment: After disabled js animation, you can do the animation only using css, put in your **.tooltip** `transition: opacity 500ms ease; opacity: 0;` and in **.tooltip.in** `opacity:1`

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I'm experiencing the exact same problem (with BS 2.3.2). I expect the issue is caused by a sequence that runs something like this: mouse exits target control, 'hide' executes with a 500ms timer that will detach the tooltip from the control after half a second. But before that timelimit expires, the mouse re-enters the control and the 'show' segment executes, drawing the tooltip on screen again... and THEN the 'hide' timer limit expires, and the associated script executes, detaching the newly re-added tooltip from the control causes it to show briefly then vanish.